# SignalR connection with API

Tags: c#, api, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

i have a web api setup in c# . which checks whether it is still connected with signalR or not, and executes codes according. This is my condition:

```
if (hubConnection != null && hubConnection.State == Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connected)
{

    hubProxy.Invoke("hubMethod", hubParams);
}
else
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["signalRPath"].ToString());
    hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
    hubConnection.Start().Wait();
    hubProxy.Invoke("hubMethod", hubParams);
}
```

The problem is when i restart my signalR server, my API keeps on invoking the hubMethod from prev connection ID rather than creating a new connection ID with signalR.

If the info i provide is not sufficient then please let me know.

Comment: When you restart do you keep connection IDs somewhere to manage on the server?

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani i dont. its basically just one connection which needs to stay open, or reconnect if server restarts or something..